# sql query error when using "with" I got an an error like 1064 syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
with firstcte (first_name,active) as(
 select first_name,active from customer)
 select * from firstcte
```

> Error Code: 1064.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'firstcte (first_name,active) as(
> select first_name,active from customer)
> select ' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064) and/or [WITH statement on MySQL syntax error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73153852/with-statement-on-mysql-syntax-error-1064)

Comment: Older versions of MySQL don't have CTE support. That's likely your problem.

Comment: With clause was added with MySQL 8.0. Check out your version using `select version()`. https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/with_(non-recursive,_top_level)